# Kubernetes beginner - cannot load the exposed service in browser

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am learning kubernetes and minikube, and I am following this tutorial:

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/

But I am running into a problem, I am not able to load the exposed service. Here are the steps I make:

```
minikube start
```

The cluster info returns

```
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:50121
CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:50121/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Then I am creating a deployment

```
kubectl create deployment hello-minikube1 --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
```

and exposing it as a service

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube1 --type=NodePort --port=8080
```

When I list the services, I dont have a url:

```
minikube service list
```

| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | hello-minikube1 | 8080 |  |

and when I try to get the url, I am not getting it, seems to be empty

```
minikube service hello-minikube1 --url
```

This is the response (first line is empty):

```
  Starting tunnel for service hello-minikube2.
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

Why I am not getting the url and cannot connect to it? What did I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using macos

Answer (score 1):

Please use `minikube ip` command to get the IP of minikube and then use port number with it.

Also, refer below link:

[https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#:~:text=minikube%20tunnel%20runs%20as%20a,on%20the%20host%20operating%20system](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#:%7E:text=minikube%20tunnel%20runs%20as%20a,on%20the%20host%20operating%20system).

Comment: Still cannot access the port in browser

Answer (score 0):

As per this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9016),the docker driver, which needs an active terminal session. Who are using macOS to use docker driver by default a few releases ago, if no local configuration is found. I believe you can get your original behavior by using the hyperkit driver on macOS:

```
minikube start --driver=hyperkit
```

You can also set it to the default using:
`minikube config set driver hyperkit`

This will help you to solve your issue.